# Почему не убирается .php в Bitrix htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, битрикс, mod-rewrite

Добавил в файл htaccess сайта на bitrix:

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [NC]

Почему не выполняется удаление **.php**, а выкидывает на страницу 404 urlrewrite?

```
</IfModule>
php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value pcre.recursion_limit 1000
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  # добавил
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]      
  RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [NC

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

В целом, в битриксе все правила обработки проходят через urlrwrite,
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/urlrewrite.php - тут в примерах есть то что тебе нужно

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]